# Python minidom element.data only returns object, not text

Tags: python, xml-parsing, minidom

I am fairly new to Python and am just trying to parse the results of a simple Web-API that returns the following XML-Syntax:

```
<rss version='2.0'>
<channel>
<title>www.onlinetvrecorder.com</title>
<description>OTR Torrents</description>
<link>http://www.onlinetvrecorder.com/</link>
<copyright>OTR</copyright>
<STATIONS>
    <ITEM>
      <TITLE>3SAT</TITLE>
      <COUNTRY>DE</COUNTRY>
      <LANGUAGE>DE</LANGUAGE>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
      <TITLE>ANIXE</TITLE>
      <COUNTRY>DE</COUNTRY>
      <LANGUAGE>DE</LANGUAGE>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
      <TITLE>ARD</TITLE>
      <COUNTRY>DE</COUNTRY>
      <LANGUAGE>DE</LANGUAGE>
    </ITEM>
</STATIONS>
</channel>
</rss>
```

My parser looks like that:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom

def parseStations(stationsResult):

    document = dom.parse(stationsResult)

    stations = []

    #get all ITEM elements and get their child TITLE
    items = document.getElementsByTagName("ITEM")

    for item in items:
        stationTitleNodeValue = item.getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].firstChild.data
        stations.append(stationTitleNodeValue);

    return stations
```

My intent is to get the text-value of the TITLE Elements in the xml. But when printing the contents of the return list to console, it looks like this:

```
<DOM Element: TITLE at 0x368e8c0>
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody of you help me?
Thank you (VERY MUCH!) in advance,

Christian

Comment: Calling your function with your data returns `[u'3SAT', u'ANIXE', u'ARD']` in Python 2.7 for me. Not sure why yours would be different.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work OK to me. You get a DOM element object, which works as a string in most contexts. So, `print x[0]` etc. (where `x` is the return value from your function) will generally get you the results you seek.

If you just want a list of the station names as strings, then convert them to strings (XML is Unicode or a subset thereof, so you should use Unicode strings):

```
stations.append(unicode(stationTitleNodeValue))
```

BTW, what you've written can be expressed more compactly in a list comprehension:

```
def parseStations(stationsResult):
    return [unicode(item.getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].firstChild.data)
            for item in dom.parse(stationsResult).getElementsByTagName("ITEM")]
```